# XSLT: Group items with or without an attribute

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to group items by attribute, and I want that items that don't have that attribute end up in a group.
Current XSLT is something like this:

```
    <xsl:for-each-group select="list/item" group-by="@myAttr">
    ...
    </xsl:for-each-group>
```

and elements without myAttr are currently ignored.
The only thing that comes to my mind is to do a for-each after that and run the same code on all the items that don't have the attribute. Is there a better way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `<xsl:for-each-group select="list/item" group-by="string(@myAttr)">` as then items without the attribute are grouped by the empty string value.

Answer (score 0):

```
group-by="(@myAttr,myDefaultValue)[1]"
```

will allow you to specify an arbitrary value to use for the absence of the attribute.